# Unable to launch Software Updater, Software & Updates, and Kazam in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, update-manager, kazam

I have a problem with some Ubuntu software. I cannot launch Software Updater, Software & Updates, and Kazam by clicking on the icons or right-clicking and then pressing New Window. In addition, I tried to launch the applications from the Ubuntu store. Unfortunately, the applications do not launch What should I do?

Personally, I do not want to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04. I will consider that solution as a last resort.

**Potential Solutions**

- Restarting it. I tried to restart my Ubuntu 18.04 browser and it does not fix the issue
- Reinstall Ubuntu

When I run `/usr/bin/update-manager` in terminal I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 38, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.UpdateManager import UpdateManager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 45, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
```

**Update:**

I installed another application called package manager and that helps me update my packages. I realized that Livepatch does not launch.

Comment: Did you mess with anything related to pre-installed Python in Ubuntu? BTW, instead of adding comments to add details to your question, you can [edit] your question and add the details in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I did. I managed to fix it.

Comment: Do write an answer to your question explaining how you managed to fix it. It'll be helpful to the community :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

1. I called `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1`
2. I called `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`
3. I select the alternative `python path` to be `Python 3.6`.